# How to use many \write to write text on just one line?

Tags: write-file

I have to use many write commands to write to the temporary file as follows

```
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=tempt.txt
\immediate\write\tempfile{data 1}
\immediate\write\tempfile{data 2}
\immediate\write\tempfile{data 3}
\immediate\write\tempfile{data 4}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
```

Output

> data 1
>
> data 2
>
> data 3
>
> data 4

How to still use multiple writes but results on just one line as

> data 1 data 2 data 3 data 4

I don't want to use `\immediate\write\tempfile{data 1 data 2 data 3 data 4}`.

Thankyou.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `\write` always adds a newline, however you can always collect up the tokens and write them all together.

For example this plain tex `\mywrite{aaa}`  and `\mywrite{bbb}` produces a file with `aaabbb`

```
\newwrite\zz
\newtoks\zzz

\def\mywrite#1{\zzz\expandafter{\the\zzz#1}}

\mywrite{aaa}
\mywrite{bbb}




\immediate\openout\zz=\jobname.zz
\immediate\write\zz{\the\zzz}
\immediate\closeout\zz

\bye
```